# OKHTTP response XMLPullParser

Tags: android, okhttp, android-xmlpullparser

I am transitioning to  OKHttp and i am using  SAXParser in my project. How can i parse the  OKHttp response to SAXParser? or how else can I parse XML using the library.
initially this was how I was doing it:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
SAXParserFactory factory1 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory1.newSAXParser();
FormHandler handler = new FormHandler();
parser.parse(inputStream, handler);
```

But with OKHTTP, how can i pass `Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()` to the XML parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this :

```
// 1. get a http response
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

// 2. construct a string from the response
String xmlstring = response.body().string();

// 3. construct an InputSource from the string
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlstring));

// 4. start parsing with SAXParser and handler object 
// ( both must have been created before )
parser.parse(inputSource,handler);
```

PS : in your question you mention XMLPullParser, in your code you're actually using a SAXParser. However, if you have the xml string on your hands, you should do fine with both ways.

Comment: Nice. You can also call response.body().charStream() to get a reader to pass to your parser. That'll use less memory if your XML document is large (ie. bigger than 1 MiB).

Comment: I'm getting ```Unexpected <! (position:START_DOCUMENT``` I believe this is because of ```<!DOCTYPE html>```, does anybody have a workaround?